# TableLayout error in Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a `XML` file containing `TableLayout` as follows:

```
    <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/resulttable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_discription"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_left_vehicle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_right_vehicle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

In the above table I want to show array list of string, for this I have done following code:

```
            TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.resulttable);
        for(int i=0;i<DArray.size();i++)
        {
            TableRow row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tr);
            String discription = DArray.get(i);
            String leftVehicle = LArray.get(i);
            String rightVehicle = RArray.get(i);

            TextView tvD = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_discription);
            tvD.setText(discription);
            TextView tvlPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_left_vehicle);
            tvlPrice.setText(leftVehicle);
            TextView tvrPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_right_vehicle);
            tvrPrice.setText(rightVehicle);

            row.addView(tvD);
            row.addView(tvlPrice);
            row.addView(tvrPrice);

            table.addView(row);
        }
```

but this code is arising exception. Here is LogCat error for my code.

> E/AndroidRuntime(1897): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I am beginner for this situation please help me find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should Try this way

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.resulttable);
TableRow row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tr);
TextView tvD = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_discription);
TextView tvlPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_left_vehicle);
TextView tvrPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_right_vehicle);
    for(int i=0;i<DArray.size();i++)
    {

        String discription = DArray.get(i);
        String leftVehicle = LArray.get(i);
        String rightVehicle = RArray.get(i);


        tvD.setText(discription);

        tvlPrice.setText(leftVehicle);

        tvrPrice.setText(rightVehicle);

        row.addView(tvD);
        row.addView(tvlPrice);
        row.addView(tvrPrice);

        table.addView(row,id);
    }
```

Provide id for row positioning

Comment: what is id at table.addView(row,**id**);

Comment: Index of table to which place you want to add your view.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you added in the `xml` the row and then you add it again and again in the loop.
If you want to have a TableLayout and add rows on it dinamicaly then you might want to create the row with its content in another xml file and inflate that xml in the for loop and then add the row to the table.

So, lets say you have the following inside another xml called row.xml:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_discription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_left_vehicle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_right_vehicle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</TableRow>
```

And the `TableLayout` in another one (xml file):

```
 <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/resulttable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3" >



    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Then you would have this in the code:

```
 TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.resulttable);

 for(int i=0; i < DArray.size(); i++){

    //get the row from the xml and add it on the table at each loop step
    TableRow row = getActivity().getLayoutInflater() .inflate(R.layout.row, table, true);
    String discription = DArray.get(i);
    String leftVehicle = LArray.get(i);
    String rightVehicle = RArray.get(i);

    // get the labels from the row and populate themm with data, note that you don't have to add them again as they are allready added..
    TextView tvD = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_discription);
    tvD.setText(discription);
    TextView tvlPrice = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_left_vehicle);
    tvlPrice.setText(leftVehicle);
    TextView tvrPrice = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_right_vehicle);
    tvrPrice.setText(rightVehicle);

 }
```

You might have to tweak the code above a bit as I wrote it from my mind and didn't tested it but that should be the trick.

Comment: did you forget to add table row?

Comment: Sorry, I added it but it seems that the formatting tool hide it somehow.. now I fixed the issue.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why Cant you use listview and custom adapters for this implementation?. which will make your life easier.

Okay the second potential problem is also: table.addView(row);

rowgets added every single loop iteration but it's the same view. You can only add a view once to the hierarchy. You probably want a new instance for each loop iteration. I can't say for sure but this is likely the problem. or try to add with index position in viewgroup like

```
 table.addView(row, index);
```